# Partition Problem while installing Ubuntu after crash

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I wanted to reset windows, in order to clean it up. But while doing that my laptop crashed.

At this point in time i have no Operating system on my laptop at all. So i tried to install Ubuntu 20.04. However for some reason this did not work. More specific it seems that i have only 1gb of space on my disk. Even so that the whole disk is empty.

What can i do to access the lost space?

When i tried the option to erase the disk and install ubuntu i get an error saying that i have not enough free space. If i try to partition it on my own, i only have approximately 1gb of space to work with. (I also run the trial version of ubuntu to try to access the partitions but even there i haven-t found a way to even display the rest of my diskspace.

Thanks for any help

Edit

As requested i run the sudo fdisk -l command and got the following output

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.98 GiB, 2103640064 bytes, 4108672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 29.9 MiB, 31334400 bytes, 61200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 255.58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 49.8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1023.102 MiB, 1073741312 bytes, 2097151 sectors
Disk model: SM2260  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.96 GiB, 16043212800 bytes, 31334400 sectors
Disk model: Flash Disk      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x13426527

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 31334399 31332352  15G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk /dev/nvme0n1
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1 259:0    0 1024M  0 disk
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you run `sudo fdisk -l` from a terminal window while using the Live USB and put the output in your question?

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: Can you run `sudo lsblk /dev/nvme0n1` and add thr result to the question?

Comment: Done that as well.

Comment: It seems to me a strange hardware problem.